# Explanation of ISTQB practice question

Tags: manual-testing

I am having trouble with this ISTQB practice question. I don't understand how the answer (A) was reached.

Q. 482: Analyze the following highly simplified procedure:

```
Ask: "What type of ticket do you require, single or return?"
IF the customer wants "return"
    Ask: "What rate, Standard or Cheap-day?"
    IF the customer replies "Cheap-day"
        Say: "That will be "11:20""
    ELSE
        Say: "That will be "19:50""
    ENDIF
ELSE
    Say: "That will be "9:75"
ENDIF
```

Now decide the minimum number of tests that are needed to ensure that all the questions have been asked, all combinations have occurred and all replies given.

```
A. 3
B. 4
C. 5
D. 6
```

Comment: Edited to make this a valuable question: it is an exact copy of an ISTQB practice question and therefore on-topic but as an un-attributed question needs to be cleaned up.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

There are 3 paths to be taken in order to achieve 100% statement coverage.

Your question does not have the best format.

```
Ask Single or Return
    IF the customer wants RETURN
        Ask Standard or Cheap-day
        IF the customer replies Cheap-day
            Say 11:20
        ELSE
            Say 19:50
        ENDIF
    ELSE
        Say 9:75 // whatever time this is
    ENDIF
```